# SQL Query with duplication key

Tags: sql, join, pivot, window-functions

I got a table like

```
KEY|VIN|MORE DATA 
1  |123| BLA BLA
2  |456|
3  |678|
4  |777|
1  |888|
```

Now I need to query so when KEY has duplication then is a different result, for example

Result

```
KEY|VIN|VIN2
1  |123|888
```

how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What's the expected result if someone inserts the row `(1,357,'xyz')`?

Comment: please tag with database.  You need to use a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, you can just use aggregation:

```
select key, min(vin) vin, max(vin) vin2
from mytable
group by key
having count(*) > 1
```

If you have more than two values per `key`, this might not do exactly what you want (only two values will be displayed in the resultset). Maybe you want to use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select 
    key, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then vin end) vin1, 
    max(case when rn = 2 then vin end) vin2, 
    max(case when rn = 3 then vin end) vin3
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by key order by vin) rn from mytable)
group by key
having count(*) > 1
```

This would handle up to three values per `key` - you can expand the `select` clause with more conditional `max()` expressions as needed.